# System.NullReferencedException Occured. object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e1)
    {
        if (e1.CommandName == "BuyClick")
        {
            Label iid_lbl = (Label)e1.Item.FindControl("iid_lbl");
            Label igid_lbl = (Label)e1.Item.FindControl("igid_lbl");
            Label iname_lbl = (Label)e1.Item.FindControl("iname_lbl");
            Label idesp_lbl = (Label)e1.Item.FindControl("idesp_lbl");
            Label iqty_lbl = (Label)e1.Item.FindControl("iqty_lbl");
            Label iprice_lbl = (Label)e1.Item.FindControl("iprice_lbl");
            Button Button1 = (Button)e1.Item.FindControl("Button1");
            str1 = "insert into orders values(' ',' ','" + igid_lbl.Text + "',' ',' ','" + iname_lbl.Text + "',' ')";
            str2 = "insert into order_item values(' ','" + iid_lbl.Text + "','" + idesp_lbl.Text + "',' ','" + iprice_lbl.Text + "','" + iqty_lbl.Text + "','" + iname_lbl.Text + "')";
            cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(str1, con1);
            cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(str2, con1);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con1.Close();
            Response.Redirect("buy.aspx");
        }

    }
```

**Error Occured in line of** `str1 = "insert into orders values(' ',' ','" + igid_lbl.Text + "',' ',' ','" + iname_lbl.Text + "',' ')";`

Comment: Side note: you should avoid building queries like that. It's hard to read (and maintain) and it's absolutely not safe (SQL injection). Use parameters like `@itemName` and then replace it using `MySqlCommand` Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to access the textbox within a grid/datalist.

If this is the case, then it's not accessible the way you're trying to do it.

you need to extract the textbox/label from the grid.

Something like this:

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e1.CommandName == "BuyClick") {
    Label igid = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("igid_lbl");
    Label iName = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("iname_lbl");

   // Do this for ALL your labels/textfields

    // now your inserts should reference these labels. Such as
    String str1 = "insert into orders values(' ',' ','" + igid.Text + "',' ',' ','" + iName.Text + "',' ')";

// ETC ETC ETC 

}
```

Comment: Even that is also gets an Error..Same Line

Comment: declare it by using `String str1` - i updated my code. same will apply for your str2...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have named the label correctly, if label doesn't exist then it may lead to concatenate null to a string that might cause the error.